# How to pad/zero extend a string to fit into this time format? (hh:mm:ss)

Tags: python

I created this time calculator that adds up the sum of two different times in the following time format, hh:mm:ss. The user is only allowed to enter their times using this format.

How does one have it that if the user for example inputs a hh + hh value of 04 and 01, it would output as 05? As of right now, it would only output a 5, which does not follow the time format I want it displayed as (hh:mm:ss). Obviously if the user has a hh + hh value that returns a value of xx as opposed to just x, I would not have any issues.

These are the relevant lines of code:

```
first_time = input("Enter time: ")
second_time = input("Enter time: ")


#Seconds calculation
first_second = int(first_time[6:])
second_second = int(second_time[6:])

#Minutes calculation
first_minute = int(first_time[3:5])
second_minute = int(second_time[3:5])

#Hours calculation
first_hour = int(first_time[0:2])
second_hour = int(second_time[0:2])


seconds_remainder = total_seconds % 60
minutes_remainder = total_minutes % 60
total_hours = first_hour + second_hour + transfer_hours

format_seconds = str(seconds_remainder)
format_minutes = str(minutes_remainder)
format_hours = str(total_hours)

total_time = str(format_hours + ":" + format_minutes + ":" + 
format_seconds)
```

Originally I just used rjust(2, '0') method which worked flawlessly, however my teacher wants us to employ string concatenation to fix this issue, so I can't use .rjust() as my score will be penalised.

edit: For this specific set of exercises we were not allowed to use if/else statements, loops, built-in functions like zfill or rjust, or format(). We had to demonstrate our understanding of what we were taught, things such as len() find/rfind and string concantenation

I'm a complete beginner at programming so please excuse my code.

Comment: "The teacher wants us to only use XYZ" doesn't work well on Stack Overflow. We don't want to guess what is or isn't on your teacher's mental list of "very basic string manipulation" techniques.

Comment: You can explicitly pad with zeros using a simple loop: `while len(format_seconds) < 2: format_seconds = '0' + format_seconds` (and similarly for all the other). That uses only string length and concatenation and basically does the same as `rjust()`.

Comment: Sorry, edited it to be precise

Comment: @DanielJunglas I was told to fix this issue using string concatenation, hence why I can't use loops or built-in functions

Comment: You have to be more specific about what exactly you are allowed to use. The loop could be changed to an `if` since you are only padding to a length of 2. But then, if you are not allowed to use `if` either, then I am out of ideas.

Comment: @DanielJunglas For this specific set of exercises we were not allowed to use if/else statements, loops, built-in functions like zfill or rjust, or format(). We had to demonstrate our understanding of what we were taught, things such as len() find/rfind and string concatenation. There were more but these were the only ones worth mentioning for my specific issue

Comment: How about: `format_seconds = '0' * (2 - len(format_seconds)) + format_seconds`?

Comment: @DanielJunglas Spot on solution, worked perfectly! I was thinking of trying something along those lines but had no clue how to execute it, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are not allowed to use if, loops, or other conditional expressions, you can use

```
format_seconds = '0' * (2 - len(format_seconds)) + format_seconds
```

The left operand of the `+` creates a string of zeros of the required length. Note that this string will be empty if `2 - len(format_seconds)` is zero or negative.

Answer (score 0):

To right-justify a string `str` to length `lng` using character `pad_ch` as padding, apply the following algorithm:

```py
str = '1'
lng = 2  # desired length
pad_ch = '0'  # padding character
pad = pad_ch * lng  # '00'
temp = pad + str  # '00..'  use 'str + pad' for left-justify

# now slice the rightmost lng characters
# use temp[:lng] for left-justify
padded_result = temp[-lng:]  # '' -> '00', '1' -> '01', '12' -> '12'
```